# $yy''-(y')^2=-y^2$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We want to solve the differential equation :

- $yy''-(y')^2=-y^2$
- $y(0)=1, y'(0)=0$

---

- $ \left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)'=\frac{yy''-y'^2}{y^2}=-1$
- therefore $y(x) =e^{ \frac{-x^2}2}$

How would you solve it, without trick, with a general method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general second order ODE has the form
$$\Psi(x,y,y',y'')=0\ ,$$
and your problem is of this sort. There are some special such equations, e.g., linear ODEs with constant coefficients, for which there is a standard algorithm. But there is no general method that solves any ODE of the above form. When you find a solution nevertheless this is not a trick, but luck.

Concerning the ODE at hand you had exactly the relevant special idea that solves it.

Comment: Thanks so much !

Answer (score 5):

Since the ODE is of the form:
$$\Psi(y,y',y'')=0\ $$
You can substitute $p=\dfrac {dy}{dx}$ and $y''=p\dfrac {dp}{dy} $. So that:
$$yy''-(y')^2=-y^2$$
Becomes:
$$yp'-p=-\dfrac {y^2}{p}$$
This is Bernoulli's differential equation.